# $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n-k}{k}=\frac{2}{3}\left(\cos\frac{\pi(n-1)}{3}+\cos\frac{\pi n}{3}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Be $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ .

This is a simple formula but not obviously :

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n-k}{k}=\frac{2}{3}\left(\cos\frac{\pi(n-1)}{3}+\cos\frac{\pi n}{3}\right)$$

Can be found a short proof for that ?

Comment: The current version of the question does not make sense. Sum of what? Is the first $=$ not meant to be there?

Comment: @Jan: Thanks a lot for the hint, was only a mistake.

Comment: @FelixMarin : Yes, thanks for the hint, I haven't known this link. :-) I have marked it as double now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html) have the following representation:
$$ U_n(x)=\sum_{r\geq 0}\binom{n-r}{r}(-1)^r (2x)^{n-2r} \tag{1}$$
hence the wanted sum is just $U_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$, and since $\frac{1}{2}=\cos\frac{\pi}{3}$,
$$ U_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\sin((n+1)\pi/3)}{\sin(\pi/3)}\tag{2} $$
and the claim is a straightforward consequence of $(2)$.

Comment: As often, I am amazed at the variety of knowledge you have. I have been working on the $U_n(x)$ but I had not paid attention to their expression.

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation. :-) ( It's different to the link above which I haven't known. )